# Orange bar on the side of chat

Tags: clash-of-clans

There is not an orange bar on the side of my chat to tell me how many new chats there are. How do I fix this?

Comment: It's possible that no one has said anything new since the last time you logged in.

Comment: No people have said chatted new things while I'm gone and the chat is not open but it never shows the orange

Comment: The "orange bar" is just the arrow button that slides the chat window out from the side of the application. When there's a new clan chat message, there will be a red square in a white boarder with the number of new messages/events. Two things of note: this is only for clan-related messages/events and there are no settings that I can find that enables or disables this.

Comment: Yeah it won't show that red button but I had it before

Comment: Are you sure that there are new **clan** messages for you to see? New global messages will not trigger the counter.

Comment: Yes I will ask a clan member a question get off the app then open it back up, no red button is there but new chat messages

Comment: Well if its happening to you, you can report it as a bug on supercell forums.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after an update (iOS) - to fix it, I exited the game then completely closed the app by sliding it up from the multitasking window on my iPhone. Once I reloaded the game, I got my chat counter back.